# Change calendar to display multiple events per day

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

since yesterday I'm thinking about a problem I have...

I'm using [this](https://blog.netgloo.com/2015/08/01/php-build-an-html-calendar/) calendar code in order to display a calendar on my website.

Here is the PHP Code for it: (I modified it a little bit to represent colors and times in calendar)

```
 // CSS classes
          $css_cal = 'calendar';
          $css_cal_row = 'calendar-row';
          $css_cal_day_head = 'calendar-day-head';
          $css_cal_day = 'calendar-day';
          $css_cal_day_number = 'day-number';
          $css_cal_day_blank = 'calendar-day-np';
          $css_cal_day_event = 'calendar-day-event';
          $css_cal_event = 'calendar-event';

          // Table headings
          $headings = ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag'];

          // Start: draw table
          $calendar =
            "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='{$css_cal}'>" .
            "<tr class='{$css_cal_row}'>" .
            "<td class='{$css_cal_day_head}'>" .
            implode("</td><td class='{$css_cal_day_head}'>", $headings) .
            "</td>" .
            "</tr>";

          // Days and weeks
          $running_day = date('N', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
          $days_in_month = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));

          // Row for week one
          $calendar .= "<tr class='{$css_cal_row}'>";

          // Print "blank" days until the first of the current week
          for ($x = 1; $x < $running_day; $x++) {
            $calendar .= "<td class='{$css_cal_day_blank}'> </td>";
          }

          // Keep going with days...
          for ($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++) {

            // Check if there is an event today
            $cur_date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
            $draw_event = false;
            if (isset($events) && isset($events[$cur_date])) {
              $draw_event = true;
            }

            // Day cell
            $calendar .= $draw_event ?
              "<td class='{$css_cal_day} {$css_cal_day_event}'>" :
              "<td class='{$css_cal_day}'>";

            // Add the day number
            $calendar .= "<div class='{$css_cal_day_number}'>" . $day . "</div>";

            // Insert an event for this day
            if ($draw_event) {
              $calendar .=
                "<div class='{$css_cal_event}'>" .
                "<a href='{$events[$cur_date]['href']}' style='color:".$events[$cur_date]['color'].";'>" .
                $events[$cur_date]['time'].' Uhr: <br/>'.$events[$cur_date]['text'] .
                "</a>" .
                "</div>";
            }

            // Close day cell
            $calendar .= "</td>";

            // New row
            if ($running_day == 7) {
              $calendar .= "</tr>";
              if (($day + 1) <= $days_in_month) {
                $calendar .= "<tr class='{$css_cal_row}'>";
              }
              $running_day = 1;
            }

            // Increment the running day
            else {
              $running_day++;
            }

          } // for $day

          // Finish the rest of the days in the week
          if ($running_day != 1) {
            for ($x = $running_day; $x <= 7; $x++) {
              $calendar .= "<td class='{$css_cal_day_blank}'> </td>";
            }
          }

          // Final row
          $calendar .= "</tr>";

          // End the table
          $calendar .= '</table>';

          // All done, return result
          return $calendar;
        }
```

Now I have two different types of appointments, which I get from my db, convert to an array and pass it as the `$events` variable:

```
$events = array();
            foreach ($partEvents as $event) {
                $events[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event['eventDate']))] = array(
                    'text' => $event['description'],
                    'href' => '/nsl/editGroupCoaching/'.$event['ID'],
                    'time' => date('H:i', strtotime($event['eventDate'])),
                    'color' => '#edb01a'
                );
            }

            foreach ($appointments as $event) {
                $events[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event['date']))] = array(
                    'text' => $event['description'],
                    'href' => '#',
                    'time' => date('H:i', strtotime($event['date'])),
                    'color' => '#00898d'
                );
            }
```

So I display the `$partEvents` in one color and the `$appointments` in the other color. In general, this is working fine, and they are displayed with the time in front of them. However, whenever there are 2 events at the same day, it doesn't work any more, because the array key is not unique any more (only 1 out of 2 events are displayed)....

What I would like to have is that there can be 1,2,3 or even 10 events on one day...

What I thought of is just changing the array generation and add `H:i:s` at the array keys, however, then there are no appointments displayed anymore at all...

How do I need to alter the code from the calendar generation, in order to be able to add multiple events per day? I tried playing around a lot with `$runningDay` and `$cur_date`, but I can't seem to get it to work.. I have to admit, that I'm not the best with multidimensional arrays though..

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add time to main event index calendar won't be able to directly determine if there is an event for given day. You could add secondary index that would be used after events for given date are found (added two local explanatory variables `$date` and `$time` - change their names in case of conflict with remaining part of the code):

```
        $events = array();
        foreach ($partEvents as $event) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event['eventDate']));
            $time = date('H:i', strtotime($event['eventDate']));
            $events[$date][$time] = array(
                'text' => $event['description'],
                'href' => '/nsl/editGroupCoaching/'.$event['ID'],
                'color' => '#edb01a'
            );
        }

        foreach ($appointments as $event) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event['eventDate']));
            $time = date('H:i', strtotime($event['eventDate']));
            $events[$date][$time] = array(
                'text' => $event['description'],
                'href' => '#',
                'color' => '#00898d'
            );
        }
```

Now you need to change the way events are displayed (potential rendering issues are left for you to solve - it'll just straight forward add copies of single event into table cell):

```
        ...
        // Insert an event for this day
        if ($draw_event) {
            ksort($events[$cur_date]);
            foreach ($events[$cur_date] as $time => $event) {
                $calendar .=
                    "<div class='{$css_cal_event}'>" .
                    "<a href='{$event['href']}' style='color:".$event['color'].";'>" .
                    $time.' Uhr: <br/>'.$event['text'] .
                    "</a>" .
                    "</div>";
            }
        }
        ...
```